# Separate bibliographies on same page

Tags: biblatex, page-breaking, subdividing

I would like to scan the bib file for entry type, put them into 3 categories, and show those separate with title. I got this working with the code below. I would like to change two things:

- Delete the strange output at the footcite (blx@hook@citekey@next);
- Put all three bibliographies below eachother, so no new page.

How can I do that?

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{websites}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{spoken}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{books}

\AtEveryCitekey{
  \ifentrytype{misc}{
    \iffieldundef{howpublished}{
      \addtocategory{websites}{\thefield{entrykey}}
    }{
      \addtocategory{spoken}{\thefield{entrykey}}
    }
  }{
  }
}

\AtEveryCitekey{
  \ifentrytype{book}{
      \addtocategory{books}{\thefield{entrykey}}
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%books
@book{3,
  author = {Menger, Carl},
  title = {Grunds{\"a}tze der Volkswirtschaftslehre},
  publisher = {Braum{\"u}ller},
  year = {1982} 
}

%spoken
@misc{4,
  author = "Janssen, Jan",
  title = "",
  month = may,
  year = "2014",
  howpublished = "Congres"
}

%websites
@misc{5,
  author = {The Guardian},
  title = {Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits},
  url = "http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banks-closed-prevent-run-deposits",
  urldate = "2014-11-15"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
Some text
\footcite{3,4,5}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[category=books,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[category=websites,title={Online articles}]
\printbibliography[category=spoken,title={Conferences}]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the error message you speak of.

Comment: That's the strange output: blx@hook@citekey@next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to lockstep's editing of the tags, I found the answer myself.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{websites}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{spoken}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{books}

\AtEveryCitekey{
  \ifentrytype{misc}{
    \iffieldundef{howpublished}{
      \addtocategory{websites}{\thefield{entrykey}}
    }{
      \addtocategory{spoken}{\thefield{entrykey}}
    }
  }{
  }
}

\AtEveryCitekey{
  \ifentrytype{book}{
      \addtocategory{books}{\thefield{entrykey}}
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%books
@book{3,
  author = {Menger, Carl},
  title = {Grunds{\"a}tze der Volkswirtschaftslehre},
  publisher = {Braum{\"u}ller},
  year = {1982} 
}

%spoken
@misc{4,
  author = "Janssen, Jan",
  title = "",
  month = may,
  year = "2014",
  howpublished = "Congres"
}

%websites
@misc{5,
  author = {The Guardian},
  title = {Cyprus banks remain closed to prevent run on deposits},
  url = "http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/mar/26/cyprus-banks-closed-prevent-run-deposits",
  urldate = "2014-11-15"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
Some text
\footcite{3,4,5}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\section*{Books}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\printbibliography[category=books,heading=none]
\endgroup

\section*{Online articles}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\printbibliography[category=websites,heading=none]
\endgroup

\section*{Conferences}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\printbibliography[category=spoken,heading=none]
\endgroup


\end{document}
```